# Script to convert rails model --> cakephp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cakephp

I am learning cakephp after learning rails and I am stunned how similar the frameworks are. I was wondering if there is an automated way to generate models from rails to -->cakephp. I know there is the cake bake script, but that will take a long time. (I have about 30 models)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a script to convert rails models to cakephp models. However, you could try

```
$ cake bake model all
```

to generate the models from your database.